# Dump tcp traffic out of container on Mac OS

Tags: linux, docker, networking, containers, virtual-machine

I have a container running and inside there is a switch emulator and a producer that sends packages to this emulator. there are various virtual ethernet interfaces inside the container for the switch. I was wondering if there is a way to dump the traffic inside the container to Mac OS to analyze it with Wireshark. The network config for the container is "host" which as I have read means sharing of the network stack with the host(since they are in the same namespace), however the host being the VM in between since it is docker desktop. is there a way to do this?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be better places for questions like this.